# TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined - Twitter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots, node-modules

Below is the output when running app.js. This started occurring totally at random when everything was working fine. Absolutely no changes were made.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
        at /home/ec2-user/environment/rt-bot/app.js:78:48
        at Request._callback (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:220:14)
        at Request.self.callback (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
        at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
        at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
```

I've tried creating new instances from my master branch (with no commits since last working) and even still getting this error. Any ideas?

**The code causing the error**, though this code was working previously.

```
T.get('search/tweets', query, function(err, data, response) {
  // continue if no errors
  if(!err){
    // loop
    for(let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++){
      // get latest tweet ID
      let id = { id: data.statuses[i].id_str }

      // try favorite
      T.post('favorites/create', id, function(err, response){

        // log failures
        if(err){
          console.log('Try Favorite - ', err[0].message);
        }

        // log success
        else{
          let username = response.user.screen_name;
          let tweetId = response.id_str;
          console.log('Favorited: ', `https://twitter.com/${username}/status/${tweetId}`)
        }

      });
```

**Image of first occurrence**. As you can see everything was functioning fine, then this error came out of nowhere with absolutely no changes to environment or codebase.

[image: As you can see everything was functioning fine, then this error came out of nowhere with absolutely no changes to environment or codebase.]

UPDATE:

Output when logging error with `console.log('Try Favorite - ', err.message);` rather than `console.log('Try Favorite - ', err[0].message);`

```
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.702]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.705]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.706]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.707]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.708]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.709]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.712]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.713]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.718]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 21:27:00.793]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
```

Also note that the retweet function uses the same console logging method. See code below, and outputs fine.

```
// try retweet
      T.post('statuses/retweet', id, function(err, response){

        // log failures
        if(err){
          console.log('Try Retweet - ', err[0].message);
        }
```

Comment: Try logging err without [0]

Comment: I'm checking rate limits currently to see if they've possibly been rate limited on favorites for the day, though typically it outputs differently, it would explain the randomness of the occurrence.

Comment: GET favorites/list rate limit is 75 per window (15 minutes), whereas GET search/tweets is 180(user) - 450(app) per window.

Running numbers for all requests quick.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, the reason I'm getting the error is because its requesting the Code 429 message rather than the "You have already favorited this Tweet" message which are likely delivered differently?

Running the numbers, though, it doesn't seem the user should be being rate limited, and the rate limit should release at the start of a new window, yet this has been occurring for much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) uses [request](https://github.com/request/request) to send HTTP requests to Twitter API, so the error will be single object not an array, so your error handler will look like

```
if(err){
  console.log('Try Favorite - ', err.message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but see the edit at the bottom, as this didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: Now you can see the real error... Too many requests... You hit some limit in twitter api

Comment: Using `err.message` instead of `err[0].message` apparently fixed the problem in the code, and showed you the cause of the issue, which is exceeding the requests rate limit https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits

Comment: You can try https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter to help you avoiding hitting the limit

Comment: I'm already using the practices within that rate limiter, but very good suggestion! I'm not sure what could be being limited. Only the post favorites/create is being limited while all other features seem to be working fine. 

I'm having trouble finding real POST limits except *hints* at 1000 per day, but there are less than 12 favorites/create POST requests and all other POST requests are going through fine.

Interestingly with console logging err.message refuses to work when NOT getting HTTP Status 429.

Comment: I misspoke in saying this didn't work, as it did, I was just presented with another error so accepted and thank you both!

This became a 3 parter so I will move on to additional questions!