# Twitter API - POST favorites/create Specific Rate Limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, twitter, rate

I was having an issue with my script crashing on a `message undefined` error which was answered here: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined - Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081097/typeerror-cannot-read-property-message-of-undefined-twitter-api/50081244#50081244)

It turned out that when hitting a rate limit, the error message is delivered differently thus `console.log('Try Favorite - ', err[0].message);` would return an error unless changed to `console.log('Try Favorite - ', err.message);`.

It now outputs as `[[Apr 28 22:26:01.024]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests` which suggests a rate limit, however, I'm not finding a clear rate limit.

All documentation for POST limits state 1000, however, I'm counting a total of 22 over the course of the lat 8 hours, so its strange that its being rate limited.

Does anyone have any more clear documentation? All links I find seem to be dead.

I might add as well,that ONLY favorites are being affected, all other requests are working fine.

EDIT: Adding output of recent. `Undefined` will be `You already ____ed this tweet`, however, due to a temporary change to keep the app from crashing, message is undefined.

```
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.560]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.562]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.563]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.564]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.575]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.578]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.583]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.584]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.589]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.592]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.593]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.599]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.604]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.609]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.619]] [LOG]   Retweeted: https://twitter.com/username/status/90374******24768
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.634]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.671]] [LOG]   Try Retweet -  undefined
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.754]] [LOG]   Try Favorite -  HTTP Error: 429 Too Many Requests
[[Apr 28 23:57:00.800]] [LOG]   Favorited:  https://twitter.com/username/status/99037*******48615
```

EDIT: Informed that I'm visibly exceeding rate limits, however this issue has only presented itself today while working for 5 days prior. As well retweets are still returning `You have already retweeted this tweet` while favorites are returning Status 429.

EDIT: Attempted on another test user with only statuses/retweet requests, went through fine. Attempted with a different test user (to avoid last test usage) favorites/create and it runs for first interval, then immediately rate limits after the 2nd request at 5 requests per 2 minutes, which means I'm being limited at 7 favorites/create requests per 4 minutes.

This leads me to believe there is a specific limit with favorites, however, still unclear while this exact interval was working for 5 days prior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't necessarily seem to be any documented favorites/create specific limitations, however, everything seems to be okay today. Not totally clear what had occurred as there were no updates posted to the [Twitter System Status](https://status.twitterstat.us/pages/history/564314ae3309c22c3b0002fa) page.

> ***The current technical limits of POST requests for accounts are:***
>
> - Direct Messages (daily): The limit is 1,000 messages sent per day.  Tweets: 2,400 per day. The daily update limit is further broken down
>     into smaller limits for semi-hourly intervals. Retweets are counted as
>     Tweets.  Changes to account email: 4 per hour.
> - Following (daily): The technical follow limit is 1,000 per day. Please note that this is a technical account limit only, and there are
>     additional rules prohibiting aggressive following behavior. Read about
>     following limits and prohibited behavior.
> - Following (account-based): Once an account is following 5,000 other accounts, additional follow attempts are limited by
>     account-specific ratios.  These limits include actions from all
>     devices, including web, mobile, phone, API, etc. API requests from all
>     third-party applications are tracked against the hourly API limit.
>     People who use multiple third-party applications with their account
>     will therefore reach the API limit more quickly.
>
> **These limits may be temporarily reduced during periods of heavy site usage.** In such cases, we will post an update on the Twitter status
>   site.
>
> This being said, it seems likely that limits were reduced at the time
>   but unreported.

As well, see Marco's answer above for useful information on the Premium APIs.

**GET Rate Limits** can also be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits), and are a bit more expanded on, however documentation doesn't state that individual POST options are limited anymore than others.

Answer (score 1):

According to [twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting), the limit for standard accounts is 15 requests per rate limit window, which is 15 minutes. So if you're sending 22 requests in less than 15 minutes, you're exceeding the limit.

> Rate limiting of the standard API is primarily on a per-user basis —
>   or more accurately described, per user access token. If a method
>   allows for 15 requests per rate limit window, then it allows 15
>   requests per window per access token.
>
> When using application-only authentication, rate limits are determined
>   globally for the entire application. If a method allows for 15
>   requests per rate limit window, then it allows you to make 15 requests
>   per window — on behalf of your application. This limit is considered
>   completely separately from per-user limits.

If you wish to increase your limits checkout [premium APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/premium-apis)

Comment: That's 22 requests over a 8 hours, so it definitely seems some other limit may be at play here?

Unfortunately the premium API is granted on an account level, so for my purpose it wouldn't work since I'm building this for other users.

I'd argue it may be global rate limits, but only favorites/create seems to be affected. Any ideas?

Comment: You never specified how far apart your requests were, so I assumed. You should give all the details if you want your question to be answered in the most precise way. So you're only doing a **total** of 22 requests to all of the twitter APIs in a span of 8 hours?

Comment: Let me ask you this, if no Tweet is favorited, will it count towards quota? My understanding is no, but solely based on how my Retweet frequency is working. If every time it was returned "You have already retweeted this tweet" counted towards quota, I'd be well over limits 10 fold.

So what's strange is solely favorites/create is affected, and even when being rate limited with the favorites/create function, retweeting is performing perfectly with no limitation.

Currently finds 10 tweets per 5 minutes and performs RT or favorite if query is met, which the query is mentioning of the user.

Comment: Every request count towards the quota, It doesn't matter the response from twitter.

Comment: statuses/retweet and favorites/create are requesting at the same frequency with no hinder in retweets, yet favorites seem to be a bit more strict. One favorite just went through a moment ago, then the next attempt it became rate limited again.

Yet retweets aren't being rate limited ever. Worth noting as well, favorites weren't being rate limited like this until today with no changes made.

I wonder if they can target limit after detecting certain automation? Though I've read the automation standards and I'm not in any breach.

Comment: Added some output in an edit to show that retweets are passing correctly, but favorites are almost always rate limited with an exception of 1 or 2 at a time. Is there anything there you can see that might be an issue?

Comment: You're clearing exceeding the rate limit, you're doing more than 15 requests to twitter in the limit window, that's the issue. Upgrade to premium API or just limit your requests.